# Python regular expression problems

Tags: python

I have a string of this type:

```
s = "//name#1  un2 //name2#1  u13 //name3#3"
```

How can I get these arrays of strings:

```
s1 [] = "//name, //name2, name3"
s2 [] = "1, 2, 3"
```

Comment: Will your data always look like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for

```
>>> s1=", ".join(re.findall("(//.*?)#\d+",s))
>>> s2=", ".join(re.findall("#(\d+)",s))
>>> s1
'//name, //name2, //name3'
>>> s2
'1, 1, 3'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This does it with just one regular expression:

```
>>> s = "//name#1  un2 //name2#1  u13 //name3#3"
>>> import re
>>> x = re.findall(r"(\S+)#(\S+)", s)
>>> [s1, s2] = [', '.join(y) for y in zip(*x)]
>>> s1
'//name, //name2, //name3'
>>> s2
'1, 1, 3'
```

Comment: @dgh: I though yours was better than mine :-)